# materialized view with nested table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following type:

```
create or replace type varchar2_arr as table of varchar2(300)
```

I try to create materialized view:

```
create table a (id varchar2(10), data varchar2(200), constraint pk_a primary key(id));
create table b (id varchar2(10), data varchar2(200), constraint pk_b primary key(id));

create materialized view log on a with rowid;
create materialized view log on b with rowid;

create materialized view mnest_ab_mv
refresh fast on commit
as
select a.rowid a_rowid, b.rowid b_rowid, varchar2_arr(a.data), b.data
from a, b
where a.id = b.id (+)
```

oracle gives me following error:

```
ORA-12054: cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view
```

What do I need to do to create materialized view with a nested table?

Comment: How have you established that the nested table is the cause of this?

Comment: @DavidAldridge, because when I remove `varchar2_arr(a.data)` column materialized view is created successfully

Comment: @michaelnesterenko Your CREATE code part is crippled. Please update it.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin, not is is not crippled, I omitted join condition because it is not important

Comment: @michaelnesterenko It is not only the `where`, you have `select` repeated twice. Post your real code and chances are higher that somebody points out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @michaelnesterenko Please post the *complete* CREATE statement for the materialized view and for both tables.

Comment: Am I the only one having a problem with the missing `FROM`?

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin, I updated sql code with real statements

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW procedure, its output may help.

Thanks

Vishad